# Python - start writing into the second row of a text file

Tags: python, text

I want to start writing into the second row of my text file.

Here is what I currently have (but this starts at the bottom of the file):

```
predicted_inp = input("What did you expect answer should be?")
actions[a] = predicted_inp
f = open("training.txt", "a")
f.write(""+predicted_inp+"" + ':' + ""+a+""+",", file=f)[1]
f.close()
```

Dismiss the input filed and the second line.

Comment: Due to the nature of files, you can't easily insert text in the middle of one. It's much easier to copy data from the file to a new file, pausing to write the next text before continuing the copy.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is for appending to the end of a file.

Read the whole file into a list, replace the second element of the list, then write it all back out.

```
with open("training.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines[1] = f"{predicted_inp}:{a}\n"
with open("training.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: if i use your 1 method it still writes at the end

Comment: You're right. I think it's because reading is buffered, so it reads past the first line.

Comment: Use the second method.

Comment: If i use write method it delites my whole text file

Comment: I don't see how that could be. It clearly only replaces `lines[1]`